# stronger hp pavillon or hp probook

Tags: laptop, processor

I am data science master student and I am planning to buy a new laptop for good quality of work. So I am confused which laptop to buy. I have two choices: hp pavillion and hp probook g5.. here are the characteristics..

```
CPU i5-8250U for both
RAM  12 GB (pavillion) 8 GB (probook)
128SSD+500HDD (pavillion) and 1TB HDD (probook)
same graphics card
```

So, by first glance pavillion is better than the probook, but the prices are the same so I was confused. I looked for an answer in forums, and there were written mainly that lower characteristics probook sometimes is better. So, can you give me some clarifications?

Comment: I'd go with the Pavillion in this case. It has more RAM and an SSD. If I'd need more than 500GB of HD space I'd just plug in an external portable drive.

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths and what about the class of the laptops ? business class probook vs low-cost pavilion?